# Kotlin : Okhttpclient correct way of creating single instance? OkHttpClient doesn't go through server ip check?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm new at android kotlin development and currently trying to solve how to correctly create a single instance of OkHttpClient for app-wide usage. I've currently sort-of* created a single instance of client and using it to communicate with the server, however currently the back-end server is not using token/userid for validation but IP check. I can log in the user no problem, but after going to another activity trying to call api, I'm being blocked access by server because apparently IP is not the same. I've used POSTMAN as well as already created a same functioning iOS app that is working with no issue. So my question is am i creating the single instance of OkHttpClient wrong? Or is OkHttpClient not suitable for this kind of ipcheck system? Should i use other library, and if yes, any suggestion and examples?

Thanks in advance

Currently i tried creating it like this :

```
class MyApplication: Application(){
    companion object{
        lateinit var client: OkHttpClient
    }
    override fun onCreate(){
        super.onCreate()
        client = OkHttpClient()
    }
}
```

Then i created a helper class for it :

```
class OkHttpRequest {
    private var client : OkHttpClient = MyApplication.client

    fun POST(url: String, parameters: HashMap<String, String>, callback: Callback): Call {
        val builder = FormBody.Builder()
        val it = parameters.entries.iterator()
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            val pair = it.next() as Map.Entry<*, *>
            builder.add(pair.key.toString(), pair.value.toString())
        }
        val formBody = builder.build()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build()


        val call = client.newCall(request)
        call.enqueue(callback)
        return call
    }

    fun GET(url: String, callback: Callback): Call {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        val call = client.newCall(request)
        call.enqueue(callback)
        return call
    }
}
```

Finally I'm using it like this :

```
val loginUrl = MyApplication.postLoginUrl
var userIdValue = user_id_textfield.text.toString()
var passwordValue = password_textfield.text.toString()

val map: HashMap<String, String> = hashMapOf("email" to userIdValue, "password" to passwordValue)

var request = OkHttpRequest()
request.POST(loginUrl, map, object : Callback {
val responseData = response.body?.string()
    // do something with response Data
}
```

And on another activity after user log in :

```
val getPaidTo = MyApplication.getPaidTo
var request = OkHttpRequest()

request.GET(getPaidTo, object: Callback{
    //do something with data
}
```

Comment: Have you used a network tracing tool to check if the requests are really going out with different local ip addresses?

Comment: @Joni Yeah, the ip address stays the same, after checking with my backend, apparently the cookie will save the token automatically for iOS, and postman. So i will have to save the cookie for the client as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use your OkHttpClient directly in every Activity or Fragment, use DI and move all of your business logic into Repository or some source of data.

Here I will share some easy way to make REST request with Retrofit, OkHttpClient and Koin, if you want use the same:

WebServiceModule:

```
val webServiceModule = module {
    //Create HttpLoggingInterceptor
    single { createLoggingInterceptor() }
    //Create OkHttpClient
    single { createOkHttpClient(get()) }
    //Create WebServiceApi
    single { createWebServiceApi(get()) }
}

/**
 * Setup a Retrofit.Builder and create a WebServiceApi instance which will hold all HTTP requests
 *
 * @okHttpClient Factory for HTTP calls
 */
private fun createWebServiceApi(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): WebServiceApi {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.REST_SERVICE_BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(WebServiceApi::class.java)
}

/**
 * Create a OkHttpClient which is used to send HTTP requests and read their responses.
 *
 * @loggingInterceptor logging interceptor
 */
private fun createOkHttpClient(
    loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .readTimeout(defaultTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(defaultTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}
```

And now you can inject your WebServiceApi everywhere, but better inject it in your Repository and then use it from some ViewModel

ViewModelModule:

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    //Create an instance of MyRepository 
    single { MyRepository(webServiceApi = get()) }
}
```

Hope this help somehow

Comment: Thanks, will try it back on monday, will need to read up on those libraries. But is my code of creating single instance of okhttpclient correct though? After i've read the doc, i've avoided calling okhttpclient and only through my helper method like what i've shared.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after i check with the back-end developer, i figured out the problem wasn't the ip address(it stays the same) but that the cookie was not saved by okhttp, both POSTMan and xcode automatically save the token returned into cookie so i never noticed that was the problem. So after googling a-bit, the solution can be as easy as this:

```
class MyApplication : Application(){
    override fun onCreate(){
    val cookieJar = PersistentCookieJar(SetCookieCache(),SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(this))

    client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(cookieJar)
        .build()
    }
}
```

With adding persistentCookieJar to gradle.